# return a custom object from QT C++ and print properties in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, bind

I've need to pass from C++ to QML an object to print it.
So, I have this .h:

```
    #ifndef SETTINGSOVEN_H
#define SETTINGSOVEN_H

#include <QObject>
#include <objects/settings.h>

class settingsoven : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    explicit settingsoven(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE Settings loadStartPage();


    Q_PROPERTY(Settings settingsObject READ getSettings WRITE setSettings NOTIFY settingsChanged)

    signals:
    void settingsChanged();

    public slots:
    Settings getSettings();
    void setSettings(Settings settingsObject);

    private:
    Settings m_settingsObject;
};

#endif // SETTINGSOVEN_H
```

and my cpp:

```
#include "settingsoven.h"
#include "objects/singleton.h"
#include "functions/jsonfunctions.h"

settingsoven::settingsoven(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

Settings settingsoven::loadStartPage()
{
    singleton::instance().settingsList = JsonFunctions::getConfiguration(singleton::instance().ovenClicked.id, singleton::instance().token_type, singleton::instance().access_token);
    m_settingsObject = singleton::instance().settingsList.at(0);
    return m_settingsObject;
}

Settings settingsoven::getSettings()
{
    return m_settingsObject;
}

void settingsoven::setSettings(Settings settingsObject)
{
    m_settingsObject = settingsObject;
    emit settingsChanged();
}
```

and follow my qml code:

```
...

Page {
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height

    Component.onCompleted: {
        settingsOvenToQML.loadStartPage();
        //console.log("test:" + configuration.gmt);

        console.log("proopertie print:" + settingsOvenToQML.settingsObject.id);
        //i need to print here the properties
    }

...
```

my custom object that i need to print in qml: 
settings

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
#define SETTINGS_H

#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>

class Settings
{
    public:
    Settings();

    QString id;
    QString gmt;
    QVariant rtc;
    QString thing_name;
    QString sw_gw;
    QVariant sw_ui;
    QString wlan_ip_address;
    QString eth_ip_address;
    QString hostname;
    qint32 mdl;
    quint32 mdl_code;
    quint32 tmp_unit;
    quint32 h2o_hdns;
    quint32 oven_no;
    quint32 alarm_wash_to;
    qint32 clean_to;
    qint8 clean_notice_to;
    qint8 decal_notice_to;
    bool gas_test;
    bool warn_decal_on;
    bool warn_prb_on;
    qint8 primary_prb;
    qint8 time_fmt;
    qint8 date_fmt;
    bool preheat_otp;
    bool cooldown_opt;
    qint8 ext_prb_type;
    qint8 haccp_scan;
    bool h2o_drain;
    bool chiller_opt;
    QString lang;
    qint8 backlight_lvl;
    QString video_ver;
    QString oven_name;
    QString video_build;
    QString os_ver;
    QString os_build;
    QString q1_ver;
    QString q1_build;
    QString q1_check;
    QString q2_ver;
    QString q2_build;
    QString q2_check;
    QString chill_ver;
    QString chill_build;
    QString chill_check;
    QString mac_addr;
};

#endif // SETTINGS_H
```

I'm new qt programmer, and i neet to understand how to print an object from qt.
I believe that my codes it's right, but don't work.
Where i'm wrong ? It's possibile print a custom object directly in qml from c++ ?
Some help ? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "*print in QML*"? Do you want to have access to the properties? Otherwise create a `Q_INVOKABLE printSettings()` to your `SettingsOven` and invoke this from QML - there you go, you print it in QML. Or do you mean like actually sending it to a printer?

Comment: I mean that I want print settingsObject in qml and call the properties like this: settingsObject.propertie, it's possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "print", but if you want to be able to access the properties of an object, it has to be either `QObject` derived, or have the `Q_GADGET` macro, so the MOC can generate the necessary meta data that QML needs in order to know what the object is.

Additionally, you will have to expose the properties in some way, public members will not work for QML. You need either `Q_PROPERTY` or to return the value via a `Q_INVOKABLE` getter.

```
#define QPROP(type, name) \
  Q_PROPERTY(type name MEMBER m_##name) \
  type m_##name;

class Settings {
    Q_GADGET
    QPROP(QString, id)
    QPROP(QString, gmt)
    QPROP(QVariant, rtc)
    // and so on
public:
    Settings();
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Settings) // last but not least
```

Comment: my problem it's that Q_IVOKABLE don't work when i start the method loadStartPage(), don't return a custom object.

Comment: As said: You need to make the returned object  (Settings) either a `QObject`, including the `Q_OBJECT` macro, or the `Q_GADGET`-macro. In the latter case you cannot have signals (AFAIK) so there won't be updates on bindings. Using either `Q_OBJECT` or `Q_GADGET` enables you to have `Q_PROPERTY`s and `Q_INVOKABLE`s. With `Q_PROPERTY` you can expose members by using the `MEMBER` keyword, but as you likely want to have signals, the better way is, to have setters and getters. If you only want to have it in `console.log` you won't need signals though.

Comment: @Mr.Developer - I added an example of what you should have, if that doesn't work, check the rest of your code.

Comment: @dtech: for the `MEMBER`-keyword, is it ok to have the member private?

Comment: I think so, I've used it with protected mostly, so it should work with private.

Comment: mkay. great! I like your macro `QPROP`.

Comment: Oh yeah, great time and typo saver, I have a whole family of those depending on the actual usage. Actually this one doesn't save all that much typing, but I have some very tricky ones that are many lines of code and involve bit operations to extract values from packed data. Which on its own is a great memory saver, I tend to have objects with dozens of bool properties, this way you can pack 32 properties in a single 32bit int, otherwise you will need 32 bools, which are 8 bits each.